# My django checkbox group is not recieving the values as valid, what do I do?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, checkbox, django-views, django-forms

im new to django and only dived into because of a student project im doind, and theres a problem with this checkbox that i dont understand...

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label>4 - Deficiência do Participante: <span>*</span></label>
                <div class="checkbox-group">
                    {% for disability in form.participant_disability %}
                    <div class="form-check">
                        {{ disability }}
                        
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
```

i tried searching, deleting, changing and nothing worked, here is the forms.py, the models.py and views.py

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from .choices import PARTICIPANT_DISABILITY_CHOICES
class Disability(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ParticipantResponse(models.Model):
    

    PARTICIPANT_DISABILITY_CHOICES = [
    ('auditiva', 'Deficiência Auditiva'),
    ('fisica', 'Deficiência Física'),
    ('intelectual', 'Deficiência Intelectual'),
    ('visual', 'Deficiência Visual'),
    ('autista', 'Transtorno Espectro Autista'),
    # Add more options as needed
]


   
    participant_disability = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=PARTICIPANT_DISABILITY_CHOICES, default=[''])
   
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Response for {self.participant_name}"
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ParticipantResponseForm
from .models import ParticipantResponse

def form_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ParticipantResponseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Convert selected disability choices to integers
            form.cleaned_data['participant_disability'] = [int(choice) for choice in form.cleaned_data['participant_disability']]

            # Save the form data without committing to the database
            response = form.save(commit=False)

            # Assign the disability choices to the response object
            response.participant_disability.set(form.cleaned_data['participant_disability'])

            # Save the response object to the database
            response.save()

            return redirect('responses')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            print(request.POST)
    else:
        form = ParticipantResponseForm()

    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})

def show_responses(request):
    responses = ParticipantResponse.objects.all()
    print(responses)
    return render(request, 'responses.html', {'responses': responses})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .choices import PARTICIPANT_DISABILITY_CHOICES
from .models import ParticipantResponse, Disability

class ParticipantResponseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    PARTICIPANT_DISABILITY_CHOICES = [(str(disability.id), disability.name) for disability in Disability.objects.all()]
    
    
    participant_disability = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=PARTICIPANT_DISABILITY_CHOICES,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=True,
        label='4 - Deficiência do Participante'
    )


    class Meta:
        model = ParticipantResponse
        exclude = []
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'birth_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'class': 'w3-input', 'id': 'id_birth_date'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ParticipantResponseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['participant_disability'].choices = PARTICIPANT_DISABILITY_CHOICES
```

if you can help me id be greatful.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one issue in your code, but do not worry, it is very normal in the beginnings of learning Django. Your project seems instructive for learning.

Firstly, in `forms.py` your `ParticipantResponseForm` initialization, you are dynamically setting the choices for participant_disability:

```
PARTICIPANT_DISABILITY_CHOICES = [(str(disability.id), disability.name) for disability in Disability.objects.all()]
```

This is correct, but it relies on the `Disability` objects already existing in your database. If there are no entries in the Disability table, your choices will be empty.

Secondly, you are using a `MultipleChoiceField` with a `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget. This is the correct way to handle multiple checkboxes. However, your model field `participant_disability` is a `CharField`, which is NOT align with the multiple choices selected by users. For multiple selections, a `ManyToManyField` would be more appropriate, or you need to handle the list of choices as a single string in the `CharField`.

Other one is, in your `form_view` function, there is an attempt to convert the disability choices to integers and then set them using `response.participant_disability.set(...)`. This is not necessary and will not work because `participant_disability` is a `CharField`. This code seems to be written as if `participant_disability` was a `ManyToManyField`.

My main recommendation is changing your `participant_disability` field in the `ParticipantResponse` model to a `ManyToManyField` that references the `Disability` model, or process the `CharField` correctly by joining/splitting the selected choices into a single string.